# Strttotime поддерживаемые форматы

Tags: php, дата

```
$date = '30/03/2016';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Выводит 1970-01-01. Разве это неправильный формат даты для функции `strtotime()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вообще, нет. `strtotime` понимает строку подобного формата только в `m/d/y`или `d-m-y`

Хотите использовать такую строку, Вам понадобится маска:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '30/03/2016');
```

А далее уже можете переписать в нужный Вам формат вывода:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

Из официальной документации:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

> Замечание: Даты в формате m/d/y или d-m-y разрешают неоднозначность с
>   помощью анализа разделителей их элементов: если разделителем является
>   слеш (/), то дата интерпретируется в американском формате m/d/y, если
>   же разделителем является дефис (-) или точка (.), то подразумевается
>   использование европейского форматаd-m-y. Чтобы избежать потенциальной
>   неоднозначности, рекомендуется использовать даты в формате стандарта
>   ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) либо пользоваться функцией
>   DateTime::createFromFormat() там, где это возможно.

Решение:

```
$date = '30/03/2016';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: То что надо,спасибо!

Comment: Чекнул) пару минут задержка просто была